# Script for uniq logs

Tags: shell

Given an input log file, each line of which contains an error, write a script to output one line for each unique error.

Example
Input:

```
2018/03/16 06:00:40 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error1, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:00:50 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error1, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:01:40 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error2, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:02:30 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error2, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:03:11 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error1, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:04:40 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error1, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:05:30 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error3, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:06:11 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error4, context: ngx.timer
```

Output:

```
2018/03/16 06:00:40 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error1, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:01:40 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error2, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:05:30 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error3, context: ngx.timer
2018/03/16 06:06:11 [error] 25100#0: *110598 [lua] NGX.lua:55: error=error4, context: ngx.timer
```

Comment: What's the specific technical problem you encountered while trying to solve this yourself, and what's the code you wrote when you encountered that problem? We don't just write your code for you here.

Comment: Whether or not this is in fact a homework exercise, [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823/14122) is relevant; note in particular the guidance to ask about a _specific_ problem with your _existing_ code.

Comment: Trivial with `sort -u` (And another argument).

Comment: Hi CharlesDuffy

Comment: I tried to get the output but not able to get the exact output

Comment: please help me, if you have any idea, how to do this